Geometric interpretation of controlled differential equations
A controlled differential equation is a differential equation $$dy(t)=F(y(t))dx(t),$$ where $x(t)$ is an input curve of bounded variation in a (finite-dimensional) vector space $V$, $y(t)$ is a response curve in another space $W$ and $F:W\rightarrow L(V,W)$ is a continuous map. We mean by a solution that $$y(t)=y(0)+\int_0^tF(y(\tau))dx(\tau))$$ with a Riemann-Stieltjes integral. I am interested in the geometric interpretation of such equations and how to generalise to curves lying in manifolds $M$ and $N$ respectively. I assume that $x(t)$ is smooth for simplicity. Then, we have:
$$ \dot{y}(t) = F(y(t))\dot{x}(t).$$
My intuition is that there is a map $\phi:M\rightarrow N$, which sends points in $M$ to points in $N$ and that $F$ corresponds to the differential of that map, i.e., $F=d\phi: T_xM\rightarrow T_yN$, but in this case, $F$ should use $x(t)$ as input (and not $y(t)$) to my understanding. I also tried to interpret $F$ as a pullback of one-forms on $N$ to one-forms on $M$, but this also seems wrong.
Furthermore, Lyons et. al in the book Differential equations driven by Rough paths interpret the function $F$ as a one-form in $M$ with values in $\mathfrak{X}(N)$, the space of vector fields on $N$. I see why we can interpret $F(\dot{x}(t))$ as a vector field on $N$, but I am not sure why the two viewpoints are equivalent. Does this mean that in vector spaces, $F$ can be interpreted as a map in $L(V,\mathfrak{gl}(W))$?
My question is: what does $F$ represent geometrically?

In terms of the controlled differential equation $ dy(t) = F(y(t))\, dx(t) $, the function $ F $ geometrically represents a one-form on the manifold $ M $ with values in vector fields on $ N $; the function $F$ geometrically represents a mapping that assigns to each point $y(t)\in N$ a linear map $F(y(t)): T_{x(t)}M \to  T_{y(t)}N$, effectively serving as a bundle morphism or homomorphism between the tangent spaces along the paths. It acts as a mechanism that "lifts" the infinitesimal movement $ dx(t) \in T_{x(t)}M $ of the input curve $ x(t) $ to an infinitesimal movement $ dy(t) \in T_{y(t)}N $ of the response curve $ y(t) $, thereby encapsulating how changes in $ x(t) $ influence the evolution of $ y(t) $ by translating directions in $ M $ into corresponding directions in $ N $ while respecting the geometric structures of both manifolds.

Thanks for the answer! This corresponds well to my intuition at least. I think my confusion came from the fact that I confused general one forms with differential one-forms, which I think we do not have here despite the similarity in notation. The latter being not so well behaved for pushforwards. I still am still confused as a one-form on $M$ should take a point of $M$ as input. So, at the cost of being pedantic, the map $F$ takes $x(t)$ as input and sends it to the map $(dx(t) \mapsto ( y(t) \mapsto F(y(t))dx(t)))$, which is the tangent map you defined?

A one-form on a manifold acts on tangent vectors, and the differential of a map relates the derivatives of paths while the pullback allows one-forms to interact across manifolds through the map.
